# I can't link a user to the Author model when creating an article

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, django-forms, author

Hello everyone I need the authorship to be automatically assigned to the user when creating an article and only he could change it. But so far, nothing is working out for me. I ask for your help.
models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author_user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name='Author name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ratting_author = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Ratting author')


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Author')

    NEWS = 'NW'
    ARTICLE = 'AR'
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        (NEWS, 'News'),
        (ARTICLE, 'Article'),
    )
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=NEWS, verbose_name='Тип')
    date_time_create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Date created')
    categoryPost = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='PostCategory', related_name='category', verbose_name='Category')
    heading = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Title')
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='Текст')
    ratting_post = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Ratting post')
```

view.py

```
class NewsCreate(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    permission_required = ('news.add_post',)
    form_class = NewsForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'news_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.category_type = 'NW'
        form.instance.author = self.request.user.author
        post.save()
        send_email_task.delay(post.pk)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py

```
class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    heading = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
    content = forms.CharField(min_length=20)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'heading',
            'categoryPost',
            'content',
        ]
```

I tried everything I could. Apparently there is still little knowledge, I'm just learning.

Answer (score 0):

**views.py**

In the `form_valid` method, make the following changes:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.category_type = 'NW'
        form.author = Author.objects.get(user=self.request.user) # Remember to import Author model. 
        post.save()
        ........
```

Another thing, in your `NewsForm` class, you are overriding fields that you have already defined in your `Post` model. The `ModelForm` class does the work of rendering the fields.